# Nest output of recursive function

Tags: ruby

I have written this piece of code, which outputs a list of jobdescriptions (in Danish). It works fine, however I would like to alter the output a bit. The function is recursive because the jobs are nested, however the output does not show the nesting.

How do I configure the function to show an output like this:

Job 1
- Job 1.1
- Job 1.2
-- Job 1.2.1

And so on...

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


def crawl(url)

  basePath = 'http://www.ug.dk'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(basePath + url))

  doc.css('.maplist li').each do |listitem|

    listitem.css('.txt').each do |txt|
      puts txt.content
    end

    listitem.css('a[href]').each do |link|
      crawl(link['href'])
    end

  end

end


crawl('/Job.aspx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def crawl(url, nesting_level = 0)    
  basePath = 'http://www.ug.dk'

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(basePath + url))

  doc.css('.maplist li').each do |listitem|
    listitem.css('.txt').each do |txt|
      puts " " * nesting_level + txt.content
    end

    listitem.css('a[href]').each do |link|
      crawl(link['href'], nesting_level + 1)
    end
  end    
end

crawl('/Job.aspx')
```

Comment: +1. you can make the most of your answer, and refactor the OP's confussing use of blank lines so it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. Pass an additional argument to the recursive function to indicate the level you are currently in. Initialize the value to 0 and each time you call the function increment this value. Something like this:

   ```
   def crawl(url, level)

     basePath = 'http://www.ug.dk'
     doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(basePath + url))

     doc.css('.maplist li').each do |listitem|

       listitem.css('.txt').each do |txt|
         puts txt.content
       end

       listitem.css('a[href]').each do |link|
         crawl(link['href'], level + 1)
       end

     end

   end
   ```
2. Make use of the `caller` array that holds the callstack. Use the size of this array to indicate the level in the recursion you are located in.

   ```
    def try
      puts caller.inspect
    end

    try
   ```

I would personally stick to the fist version as it seems easier to read, but requires you to modify the interface.

Comment: the first option is the natural thing to do, the second is so, so hacky, I wouldn't even mention it... (ok: you also say it)